# VPN that gives me an internal IP and allows me to reach the internal network from outside

Tags: networking, centos, vpn, openvpn, private-network

Using Red hat linux/CentOS. Where I have 1 Public IP, that is accessible remotely via SSH. Now that server needs to connect one VPN Server so that VPN server can give one IP to our Server. Now from our server we need to then ping local ip such as 10.x.x.10 which is located behind there VPN server.

What VPN client do we use for such to achieve? What type of VPN client which allows to use such thing?

There are IPSec host to host and network to network but confusing is what means what? Do I just use IPSec host to host or I need to do network to network?

Another problem is if the VPN connection is made, how can I access my server remotely using SSH? Cause most of the time when VPN is connected then the public IP is not reachable anymore.

Can anyone advise for my CentOS/RHEL what type of VPN client I need to install and configure? (very confusing I know what I need but I do not know there standard names to explain my other end point ICT team).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A VPN network usually uses a different interface on your host so you can still use your other interface and public IP. So, you will still be able to access your SSH server as before.

The usual implementation used to set up a VPN network is `openvpn` (clientside and serverside). The whole configuration process is a bit long to be described entirely here and it depends on your specific needs. Here are three links to get you started.

- [Official OpenVPN site quickstart](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/78-static-key-mini-howto.html)
- [Debian wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/OpenVPN)
- [CentOS wiki](http://wiki.centos.org/EdHeron/CentOS5OpenVPN)

The second link is from the Debian wiki but the configuration is identical for CentOS. The third link will give you specific details about `openVPN` installation on CentOS.